# Highest Sum Array List

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, formulas, array-formulas

I have a list of values and names and I would like a single cell formula to return only the greatest summed value in the list.
I actually got this to work in Microsoft excel with:

```
  =MAX(SUMIFS($A:$A,$B:$B,$B:$B,$B:$B,"<>"))
```

but now I'm required to put it into Google-Sheets and it's giving me issues,

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MAX(SUMIFS(F:F,G:G,G:G,G:G,"<>")))
```

This sort of works, but it only counts the same value as the row the formula is on. I'm not as familiar with sheets as I am excel, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Guess I don't need the second criteria. It does not appear to pickup blanks anyway. =ARRAYFORMULA(MAX(SUMIFS(F:F,G:G,G:G))), still the same issue as above however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `SUMIF` instead:

```
=Max(ArrayFormula(SumIf(G:G,G:G,F:F)))
```

Comment: I feel like this should not work- but I don't quite get why Google-sheets does somethings. It ignores blank cells in the "G" column automatically even if there is a value in 'F', thus this is exactly what I am looking for. So simple. Thank you Slai.

Comment: @L.P. most aggregate functions like Sum and Average ignore non-numeric values like text, Boolean, and empty. Also, the SumIf and SumIf**s** seem to behave differently when used in array formula